# Trouble with accurately removing Nodes in a LinkedList

Tags: java

I wrote the following class for building a LinkedList with single values on top of a given code template.

.
.

```
public class LinkedElement<T> {

    private T name;
    private LinkedElement<T> link;

    public LinkedElement(T value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value of the i-th linked element, assuming the current element to
     * be at index 0.
     * 
     * @param i 0-based index of the element whose value to return.
     * @return the i-th element's value, or {@code null} if there is no element with
     *         that index.
     */
    public T get(int i) {
        int iterator = i;

        if (iterator == 0) {
            return this.name;
        }
        if (this.link == null) {
            iterator = 0;
            return null;
        }
        if (iterator > 0) {
            iterator = iterator - 1;
            return this.link.get(iterator);
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * Adds a new linked element holding the given value at the end of the linked
     * elements.
     * 
     * @param newVal the new value.
     */
    public void add(T newVal) {
        if (this.link == null) {
            this.link = new LinkedElement(newVal);
        } else {
            this.link.add(newVal);
        }

    }

    **/**
     * Removes the i-th element from the linked elements. If {@code i == 0}, this
     * will effectively remove the head element. Thus, this method returns the
     * linked element that is the new head element.
     * 
     * @param i index of the element to remove.
     * @return the new head element.
     */
    public LinkedElement<T> remove(int i) {
        // Store i as changeable iterator
        int iterator = i;
        // Store current head element;
        LinkedElement<T> tempNode = this;
        // If head element itself is to be removed
        if (iterator == 0) {
            if (this.link != null) {
                this.name = this.link.name;
                this.link = this.link.link;
            }
            if (this.link == null) {
                this.name = null;
                this.link = null;
            }
            return this;
            // If the element is further down in the linkedlist
            // iterate through list and invoke "remove" at the desired position inside
            // the list
        }
        if (iterator > 0) {
            iterator = iterator - 1;
            return this.link.remove(iterator);
        }
        return null;**

    }

}
```

The "remove" method seems to work fine when I remove just one element and print the elements out one by one. The trouble starts when I declare a new headElement through a remove method (which returns the new headElement in that respective list)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // An example
    LinkedElement<String> headElement = new LinkedElement<String>("Yo!");
    headElement.add("LA");
    headElement.add("is");
    headElement.add("about");
    headElement.add("to");
    headElement.add("witness");
    headElement.add("another");
    headElement.add("sunny");
    headElement.add("day!");

    System.out.println(headElement.get(7));          // prints "sunny"
    headElement = headElement.remove(6);  // removes "another"
    headElement = headElement.remove(0);  // removes "Yo!"
    System.out.println(headElement.get(0));          // prints "sunny"

}
```

The expected output should be:

- sunny
- sunny

but I get

- sunny
- null

---

Question updated because I worded myself poorly.

Comment: What you get is the regular behaviour of a linked list. When you remove an element then everything gets reordered. That is how it should work.

Comment: Are you sure you want your `LinkedList` to work this way? The main reason why one should use a `LinkedList` is that you want the contents of the list to be shifted after every remove call. You can however add a different remove method that removes multiple elements in one single call but that contradicts the whole purpose of a `LinkedList`.

Comment: I updated the question with a much more relevant test code and detailing my problem more accurately. Please excuse me for having worded myself poorly earlier.

Comment: What happens to all the words before "sunny" because you're only removing "another" and they all disappear??

Comment: down-vote also since seems more like copy-paste, but since didn't see any previous answers regarding `remove` on this question one is provided also. Similar answers to the question could be found even here but context is not quite the same even if solving is similar

Answer (score 0):

because your headElement after remove(0) is:

```
LinkedElement<String> headElement = new LinkedElement<String>("what's");//0
headElement.add("up!");//1
headElement.add("That's");//2
headElement.add("Mitch");//3
headElement.add("Jones!");//4
```

and then you remove(2) from result above: which is "That's"; //at index 2
so yo get:

```
LinkedElement<String> headElement = new LinkedElement<String>("what's");//0
headElement.add("up!");//1
headElement.add("Mitch");//2
headElement.add("Jones!");//3
```

**Try to print after remove(0) and you can get what is happening!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public LinkedElement<T> remove(int i) {
        int iterator = i;
        // Store current head element;
        LinkedElement<T> tempNode = this;
        // If head element itself is to be removed
        if (iterator == 0) {
            if (tempNode.link != null) {
                tempNode.name = tempNode.link.name;
                tempNode.link = tempNode.link.link;
            }
            if (tempNode.link == null) {
                tempNode.name = null;
                tempNode.link = null;
            }
            return tempNode;
            // If the element is further down in the linkedlist
            // iterate through list and invoke "remove" at the desired position inside
            // the list
        }
        if (iterator > 0) {
            iterator = iterator - 2;
            return tempNode.link.remove(iterator);
        }
        return tempNode;
    }
```

Comment: I updated the question with a much more relevant test code and detailing my problem more accurately. Please excuse me for having worded myself poorly earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Might try the following

```
public class LinkedElement<T> {

    private T value;

    private LinkedElement<T> linkToNextElement;

    public LinkedElement(T element) {
        value = element;
        linkToNextElement = null;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LinkedElement<String> head = new LinkedElement("a");
        head.add("b");
        head.add("c");
        head.add("d");
        head.add("e");
        LinkedElement<String> newHead = head;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "]=" + head.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Head: value="+newHead.value+"\n");
        
        System.out.println("###remove(1)###");
        newHead =  head.remove(1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "]=" + head.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Head: value="+newHead.value+"\n");
        
        System.out.println("###remove(3)###");
        newHead =head.remove(3);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "]=" + head.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Head: value="+newHead.value+"\n");
        
        System.out.println("###remove(0)###");
        newHead =head.remove(0);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "]=" + head.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Head: value="+newHead.value+"\n");
        
        System.out.println("###remove(0)###");
        newHead =head.remove(0);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "]=" + head.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Head: value="+newHead.value+"\n");
        
        System.out.println("###remove(i)###");
        newHead =head.remove(7);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "]=" + head.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Head: value="+newHead.value+"\n");
        
        System.out.println("###remove(0)###");
        newHead =head.remove(0);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "]=" + head.get(i));
        }
        //empty List
        if(newHead == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Head: value= NULL : no value for emplty list" );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value of the i-th linked element, assuming the current element to
     * be at index 0.
     * 
     * @param i 0-based index of the element whose value to return.
     * @return the i-th element's value, or {@code null} if there is no element with
     *         that index.
     */
    public T get(int i) {
        int counter = 0;
        LinkedElement<T> currElement = this;
        if (i == 0) {
            return value;
        }
        while (counter < i) {
            if (currElement.linkToNextElement != null) {
                currElement = currElement.linkToNextElement;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return currElement.value;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new linked element holding the given value at the end of the linked
     * elements.
     * 
     * @param newVal the new value.
     */
    public void add(T newVal) {
        if (linkToNextElement == null) {
            linkToNextElement = new LinkedElement<T>(newVal);
        } else {
            linkToNextElement.add(newVal);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the i-th element from the linked elements. If {@code i == 0}, this
     * will effectively remove the head element. Thus, this method returns the
     * linked element that is the new head element.
     * 
     * @param i index of the element to remove.
     * @return the new head element.
     */
    public LinkedElement<T> remove(int i) {
        int counter = 0;
        LinkedElement<T> currElement = this;
        LinkedElement<T> prevElement = null;
        LinkedElement<T> nextElement = null;
        if (i == 0) {
            if (currElement.linkToNextElement != null) {
                nextElement = currElement.linkToNextElement;
                value = nextElement.value;
                if (nextElement.linkToNextElement != null) {
                    linkToNextElement = nextElement.linkToNextElement;
                } else {
                    linkToNextElement = null;
                }
                // ;
                return nextElement;

            } else {
                value = null;
                linkToNextElement = null;

            }
            return linkToNextElement;
        }
        while (counter < i) {
            if (currElement.linkToNextElement != null) {
                prevElement = currElement;
                currElement = currElement.linkToNextElement;
            } else {
                return this;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        if (currElement.linkToNextElement != null) {
            nextElement = currElement.linkToNextElement;
            prevElement.linkToNextElement = nextElement;
        }
        // last element
        else {
            prevElement.linkToNextElement = null;

        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Output

```
list[0]=a
list[1]=b
list[2]=c
list[3]=d
list[4]=e
list[5]=null
list[6]=null
Head: value=a

###remove(1)###
list[0]=a
list[1]=c
list[2]=d
list[3]=e
list[4]=null
list[5]=null
list[6]=null
Head: value=a

###remove(3)###
list[0]=a
list[1]=c
list[2]=d
list[3]=null
list[4]=null
list[5]=null
list[6]=null
Head: value=a

###remove(0)###
list[0]=c
list[1]=d
list[2]=null
list[3]=null
list[4]=null
list[5]=null
list[6]=null
Head: value=c

###remove(0)###
list[0]=d
list[1]=null
list[2]=null
list[3]=null
list[4]=null
list[5]=null
list[6]=null
Head: value=d

###remove(7)###
list[0]=d
list[1]=null
list[2]=null
list[3]=null
list[4]=null
list[5]=null
list[6]=null
Head: value=d

###remove(0)###
list[0]=null
list[1]=null
list[2]=null
list[3]=null
list[4]=null
list[5]=null
list[6]=null
Head: value= NULL : no value for empty list
```